# MQL4 Expert Advisor Error #134 'Not Enough Money' When executing Only Sell Trade

Tags: mql4

I am coding a bot to execute trades for me when I receive them on my email. I have achieved this however, I have run into a small problem I can't seem to solve. When a buy trade is placed by the EA, it runs smoothly and places the trade. However, when a sell trade is placed, it throws an error #134.

> MQL4 Website
>
> `ERR_NOT_ENOUGH_MONEY` 134 : Not enough money.

Here is my code:

```
  int placeOrder = OrderSend(
     trade,  
     type,                  
     MarketInfo(getResult(trade, " "), MODE_MINLOT),
     buy ? Ask : Bid,                                // for the market price
     3,                                              // do this if it doesnt move more than slippage
     buy ? Ask-100*_Point : Bid+100*_Point,          // Stop loss 100 points
     buy ? Ask+200*_Point : Bid-200*_Point,          // Take profit 200 points
     "ANBai trade",                                  // comment
     0,                                              // no id number
     0,                                              // no expiration date
     Green                                           // draw green arrow
  );

  if(placeOrder<0){
     return raw + " OrderSend failed with error #"+ error(GetLastError()) +"\n\n";
  }else{
     return raw + " Trade executed!\n\n";
  }
```

As you know, we buy at ask and sell at bid. This error does not happen on BUY, as much as I place many trades.

Comment: You need to take the `getResult` call out of the MarketInfo function and Market info out of ordersend and use the debugger to step through. I suspect that the MarketInfo is returning a value that you're not expecting.

Comment: Oh sorry no @nicholishen, i have logged the function, `getResult(trade, " ")` this is equal to USDCAD or any other symbol i send. get result returns string symbol